# pagination using MySQL database and Java ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, pagination

To implement a pagination on a list, I need to do two queries:

1. Get elements count from selected table using SELECT COUNT(*)...
2. Get subset of list using LIMIT and OFFSET in a query.

Are there any way to avoid this?. Are There any metadata where this is stored?

The function resultSet.getRow() retrive the array index of list, then I need to make a query whose results are all rows. After I get a subSet but this is expensive so.

I want send a only query with limits and offsets and retrive the selected datas and total count of datas.

is this possible?

Thanks in advance,
Juan

Answer (score 0):

I saw some things about this, then new doubts are coming on to me.

When a query is lanched with limits, we can add SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * on "select" section as follow:

"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ... LIMIT 0,10"

After, I query the follow:

"SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"

I understand that first query store count in a internal var whose value will be returned on second query. The second query isn't a "select count(*) ..." query so "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()" query should be inexpensive.

Am I right?

Some test that I have made show the follow:

--fist select count(*), second select with limits--

Test 1: 194 ms

out: {"total":94607,"list":["2 - 1397199600000","2 - 1397286000000","13 - 1398150000000","13 - 1398236400000","13 - 1398322800000","13 - 1398409200000","13 - 1398495600000","14 - 1398150000000","14 - 1398236400000","14 - 1398322800000"]}

--the new way--

Test 2: 555 ms
out: {"total":94607,"list":["2 - 1397199600000","2 - 1397286000000","13 - 1398150000000","13 - 1398236400000","13 - 1398322800000","13 - 1398409200000","13 - 1398495600000","14 - 1398150000000","14 - 1398236400000","14 - 1398322800000"]}

Why the test dont show the expected result?
My assumptions are wrong?

thanks, regards

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the question

The next link has got the response.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/